# Codeigniter active record issue

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

Ok, so I have following SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO film_genre
    (film_id, genre_id)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3)
```

I need to convert this into codeigniters active records and this is what I got so far but I only get one data entry out of three:

```
     $movie_genre = array(
            'film_id' => $movies['id'],
            'genre_id' => 1, 
            'film_id' => $movies['id'],
            'genre_id' => 2, 
            'film_id' => $movies['id'],
            'genre_id' => 3, 
            );

$this->db->insert('film_genre', $movie_genre );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you execute a `print_r($movie_genre)` before your insert you will see that there is just a single value for `film_id` and `genre_id`.  This is because there can be only one value for each key in an array.  You are defining three values for each key, so your earlier values are getting overwritten.

If you format your array as follows, you can use the `insert_batch` method.  See a full description of the method at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

```
$records = array(
    array('film_id' => 1, 'genre_id' => 1),
    array('film_id' => 1, 'genre_id' => 2),
    array('film_id' => 1, 'genre_id' => 3)
);

$this->db->insert_batch('film_genre', $records);
```